# Does Java Messaging Service (JMS) has a look alike or same structure on PHP?

Tags: java, php, jms

Is there a look a like structure of JMS on PHP which can be implemented? JMS can run only on ApacheMq which I have developed a system on PHP that runs on Apache which if I run both only one is running. I dont have to have another server to run JMS? Is there look alike which can be run to Apache?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, JMS only runs on Java or a native compiled version e.g. Tibco EMS.  These servers have clients for a wide range of languages and you shouldn't need to know what language the server uses for its implementation.

You could build a PHP version of JMS. But I would be surprised if one exists.

BTW ActiveMQ is not the only JMS server, there are many others. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Provider_implementations